# LINQ Group By where statement

Tags: c#, linq

**I am having trouble composing the following LINQ query.**

The `ModelResponses`collection has a collection of `Attribute` types.  I would like to select the ModelResponses that have a unique "Name", which is stored inside one of the elements in the `Attributes` collection (in `Attribute.Value` where `Attribute.Id` == 5).

The below is what I have, which doesn't seem to work.  I think I am getting the logic incorrect inside of the `GroupBy()`.

```
var test = deserialized.ModelResponses.
    GroupBy(
       x => x.Attributes.Where(attr => CasApiConversions.ToInt64(attr.Id) == 5).
           Select(y => new {y.Id, y.Value})
    ).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

**ModelResponse class:**

```
public partial class ModelResponse
{

     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("attribute")]
     public Attribute[] Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

**Attribute class:**

```
public partial class Attribute
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string[] Value { get; set; }
}
```

ModelResponse[0].Attribute.Value[0] = "MyModel" (where Attribute is Attribute.Id == 5)
  ModelResponse[1].Attribute.Value[0] = "MyModel" (where Attribute is Attribute.Id == 5)

I would like my LINQ query to only give me the first ModelResponse since the Attribute Value when Attribute.Id == 5 is identical between the two ModelResponse.

Comment: `syntax` or  `logic` ? first one can easily be detected by the compiler...

Comment: Sorry, I am getting the logic wrong.  This compiles fine, but does not eliminate the ModelResponse with the duplicate name.

Comment: can you show some sample data, and an example of the required result? The way you're asking, it's unclear what you are thying to get at.

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one class

```
    public partial class ModelResponse
    {

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string[] Value { get; set; }
    }
​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var SortByGroup = deserialized.ModelResponses.SelectAll(
       x => x.Attributes.Where(x=> CasApiConversions.ToInt64(x.Id) == 5).
           Select(y => new {y.Id, y.Value})
    ).Select(x => z.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: I thin you should use selectAll

Comment: SelectAll()?  Do you mean SelectMany()?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to try

```
.ToList().Distinct()
```